# If I multiclass from Arcane Trickster rogue to Warlock, can I swap some of my AT cantrips for warlock cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

I started out out as an Arcane Trickster rogue 7, so I could only pull from Wizard spells and cantrips, but now I have multiclassed into Warlock.

**Am I able to change some of my AT cantrips to Warlock cantrips?**

Comment: I was asking because I only have wizard cantips right now because before I level into Warlock that all I could get being a arcane trickster.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can change your existing known wizard cantrips when you multiclass into warlock?

Comment: Yes,  that exactly what I was asking.

Comment: Related: [Can an Arcane Trickster or Eldritch Knight retrain cantrips known?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115979/can-an-arcane-trickster-or-eldritch-knight-retrain-cantrips-known), [Can certain classes replace cantrips with other spells when they level up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115973/can-certain-classes-replace-cantrips-with-other-spells-when-they-level-up), [How to allow cantrips to be changed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68718/how-to-allow-cantrips-to-be-changed)