# Has there been an errata that allows cantrips to be swapped out upon levelling up?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, character-levels, errata, retraining

Based on the Q&A ["Can certain classes replace cantrips with other spells when they level up?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115973/35259), it appears that, RAW, cantrips cannot be swapped out on level up like other spells can be (for classes that can swap out spells on level up, such as Sorcerers).

However, in last night's game, some of my fellow players mentioned to me how there has been a recent errata that now officially allows cantrips to be swapped out like spells (basically, the conclusions that the above linked Q&A have now been contradicted by errata).

I have tried to search for this errata, but I can only find evidence to the contrary (i.e. supporting the linked Q&A), but what I've been able to find may not be the most recent errata that my fellow players were referring to.

Is what they claim true about there being an errata that now allows this? Or were my fellow players mistaken?

Comment: Related: [How to allow cantrips to be changed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68718/how-to-allow-cantrips-to-be-changed)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What they were referring to was probably Cantrip Versatility, which first appeared in [Unearthed Arcana: Class Feature Variants](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf) in November 2019. This is not errata, but rather playtest content.

The playtest document grants Cantrip Versatility to clerics, druids, and wizards (the spellcasting classes in the PHB that prepare spells). For instance, [the cleric's Cantrip Versatility feature](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf#page=3) reads:

> Whenever you gain a level in this class, you can replace one cantrip you learned from this Spellcasting feature with another cantrip from the cleric spell list.

Each of those 3 classes has an identically named feature in the document with nearly the same wording (replacing "cleric spell list" with "druid spell list" or "wizard spell list" respectively). It is an enhancement of the Spellcasting feature for those classes.

As Unearthed Arcana content, it is not official yet but is being play tested.

Comment: And just to clarify: This is _not_ errata but, as Steve says, unofficial ideas and concepts for playtesting. Its always a DMs choice as to how to run a game of course, but Unearthed Arcana content is experimental and even 'more optional' as to whether a DM feels like trying it out or not.

Comment: I managed to get the player who originally told me this to track down this errata for me... and he came back with this UA article; he claims he swares he's seen it as actual errata too, but at this point that's looking unlikely. I believe it was this UA all along. Unless he manages to actually find some hidden errata, I can make an answer then and accept that, but since I doubt that will happen, I'm accepting this as the correct answer.

Comment: This UA made it into Tasha's so it's an RAW optional rule now.

Answer (score 13):

**Disclaimer:** This was originally a comment but I was asked to submit it as an answer.

---

> Can cantrips be swapped out on leveling up after the release of any
>   recent errata?

I'm not sure, however:

#### Consider Allowing Spells (and Cantrips) Exchange for All on Leveling Up Either Way

We've been using the following house rule for years in my group:

> Every time you level up you can choose to exchange one spell of your
>   choice (including cantrips) for another spell of the same level. The spell must come from the list of the available spells of the class. This applies to ***all*** spellcasters.

The reasoning behind this house rule is that sometimes a spell may sound amazing but have little to zero practical effect on a campaign. Also, sometimes a player may misunderstand how exactly a spell works (e.g., she may omit an important sentence). This is very common with people whose English is not their main language.

Understandably, when that happens the player is dissatisfied. But with this simple fix, everyone is happy. I've been using this rule for the last 4 years and I never felt that it was abused or broke the balance of the game.

Comment: Related: [How to allow cantrips to be changed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68718/how-to-allow-cantrips-to-be-changed)

Comment: Agreed, and I would go even further - many games I've played and run have used a rule of "You can change any mechanics of your character (feats, spells, class ability choices, etc) between sessions, as long as it doesn't change them too much conceptually."  It hasn't caused any problems, and has reduced character switching overall.